# Why does my formatted string repeat here?

Tags: python-3.x, string, floating-point, formatting

I'm making a loop to see how many calories will be burned every 5 minutes (starting at 10 minutes) and ending at 30 minutes.

```
    x = 30
    cals = 0
    mins = 0 
    while x > 0:
        
    x -= 5
    mins += 5
    cals += 4.2
    strcals = str(format(cals, '1'))
    if mins > 5:
        print(f"After {mins} minutes, you have burned {strcals} calories")
```

When I run this program, it works just fine. My loops work for finding the amount of calories burned per minute and it ends at 30. However, once I reach 15 minutes something weird happens in the output

```
After 10 minutes, you have burned 8.4 calories
After 15 minutes, you have burned 12.600000000000001 calories
After 20 minutes, you have burned 16.8 calories
```

Can someone explain why I get this output from my program at 15 minutes? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Please fix indentation of your code.

Answer (score 0):

> why I get this output

`4.2` is not encoded exactly as 4.2 since is is not exactly representable as a floating point number.  Instead a nearby value is used 4.2000000000000001776....

Further, repeated summing can incur precision problems too (even if the above was exact), eventually adding up into `cals` renders a value near, 12.6, but not exactly.

---

> What can I do to fix it?

- Limit precision of output.
- Reduce likelihood by not repeatedly incrementing.  `cals = min * (4.2 / 5.0)`.